# static:: vs. self:: - are there any downsides?

Tags: php, static, constants, self, late-static-binding

In [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613594/overriding-class-constants-vs-properties) I learned that `self::` was not inheritance-aware where `static::` was (in PHP). When it comes to defining a bunch of constants within a class, if you want to override those constants in a subclass to change default "behaviours", it becomes necessary to use `static::` so that a method on the parent class that references the constant, honours the "override".

In the 2 years since I asked that original question, I have started using `static::` extensively, to the point that I rarely use `self::` since `self::` would appear to limit the extensibility of a class that uses constants, where `static::` does not have this limitation.

Even if i don't *currently* intend a constant to be overridden in a child class, I end up using `static::`, just in case - so I don't have to do a bunch of search-and-replace later, if it turns out I will want to extend the class and override the constant.

However, in others' code, I **rarely** see any use of `static::`. To the point that, up until 2012, I didn't even know it existed. So why is it not a general practice to use `static::` in the place of `self::` as a matter of course?

My question, then, is: are there any obvious *downsides* to using `static::` for refering to class constants, as opposed to `self::`? Am I guilty of using a gross anti-pattern here?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it depends only on the use you need. If you need to access the constant of the class in which you are calling it, use `self`. If you need late static binding use `static`.

From the point of view of performances, `self` and `static` are pretty equivalent.

Also be aware that **extensive** usage of static combined to override/inheritance is not a great idea.

For a direct answer to your question, I would always prefer the use of `static` for testing purpose (altho now PHPUnit 4 removed the support for mocking static methods).

Comment: thanks for the answer! Why is "extensive usage of static" not a great idea? Please explain. Also, why is static preferable for testing purposes?

Comment: there are lots of useful information about this topic: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/

Comment: I know PHP has moved on a lot since this question was posed but thought it was worth noting - `self::` appears to inherit from the parent when used within a child class and, from the questions I've seen around this, apparently `self::` in parent context does not get overridden by the child class. So `static::` should be used in parent context but `self::` is perfectly adequate in child context.