# Why does php allows const to be changed in subclasses?

Tags: php, constants

I don't understand why the following code works. Isn't `STEALTH` being redefined in the subclass... although it is declared as `const` in the parent? FYI, I was under the impression that `const` prevents the variable from being redefined!

```
  class Person {
    const STEALTH = "MINIMUM";
  }

  class Ninja extends Person {          
    const STEALTH = "MAXIMUM";
  }

  echo Ninja::STEALTH; // prints out 'MAXIMUM'
```

Please note that I am not asking about the scope resolution operator. I think I understand the difference between printing out `Ninja::STEALTH` vs `Person::STEALTH`. I am just surprised at the fact that ninja is able to inherit a const variable and yet have the ability to redefine it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding class constants vs properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613594/overriding-class-constants-vs-properties)

Comment: Who said it is redefined?

Comment: `Person::STEALTH` and `Ninja::STEALTH` are clearly two different things…

Comment: @deceze Yes, I can see that. I am not asking about the scope resolution operator. I am surprised at the fact that ninja is inheriting person and yet able to redefine `STEALTH`.

Comment: There's __no__ redefining here. You have __two__ different constants.

Comment: @u_mulder But then if I don't have that "second" constant redefinition... and `echo Ninja::STEALTH`, I would be able to print out the parent's value `MINIMUM`? It seems like the value IS being inherited.. and if that is the case, then why I am able to define a NEW constant with the SAME name of a constant that already exists via inheritance? Normally, I understand overriding... but in this case, how am I able to override a `const` variable?

Comment: Stop thinking in `values`, think in `items`. You have `item` of type `constant` in class `Person`. As class `Ninja` inherits class `Person`, class `Ninja` knows about every `item` (which is not private) of parent class. So, class `Ninja` knows about `item` of type `constant`. Now, you define new `item` of type `constant` with same name in class `Ninja`. So you have __two__ items: one `item` from parent class and second `item` in `Ninja` itself.

Answer (score 1):

> I was under the impression that const prevents the variable from being redefined!

`const` prevents the value to be modified.

It is not possible to define two different objects that has the same name using [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php). It is also not possible to define two different objects that has the same name using `const`. A `const` class member is always accessed using its full name (class name + `::` + constant name).

The name of the `STEALTH` constant defined by the `Person` class is `Person::STEALTH`. The `Ninja` class declares the constant `Ninja::STEALTH`.

They are different objects.

`const` (and `static`) class properties are not inherited the same way instance properties are. If a `const` property defined by the base class is not masked by another object with the same name defined by the child class, the base class `const` property is copied in the child class and can be accessed using the child class name.

For example:

```
class Person {
    const STEALTH = "MINIMUM";
}

class Citizen extends Person {

}

class Ninja extends Person {          
    const STEALTH = "MAXIMUM";
}

echo Person::STEALTH;    // prints out 'MINIMUM'
echo Citizen::STEALTH;   // prints out 'MINIMUM'; same as Person::STEALTH 
echo Ninja::STEALTH;     // prints out 'MAXIMUM'
```

Because class `Citizen` extends class `Person` and it doesn't define its own `STEALTH` constant, `Citizen::STEALTH` is a copy of `Person::STEALTH`<sup>1</sup>.

Class constants are global objects with fancy names (and class visibility modifiers since PHP 7.0).

Comment: Okay... that makes more sense to me now! Thank you!

Comment: It seems `const` variables ARE inherited. I commented out `const STEALTH = "MAXIMUM";` in the Ninja class.. and was still able to print out `Ninja::STEALTH`. It printed the inherited value of `MINIMUM`.... I am confused all over again!

Comment: Indeed, both `const` and `static` class properties of the base class can be accessed from the child class using the name of the child class. From this point of view, they are inherited. What I meant is that `Ninja::STEALTH` is the same object as `Person::STEALTH` and not a copy. This is troublesome on `static` properties (not that troublesome on `const` because they cannot be changed). I guess I will reformulate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`const` merely means that the value cannot be *altered at runtime*. It does not restrict classes from independently defining a constant by the same name; the only thing is that inheritance rules will define when and how the parent's value may get shadowed by the child's.